# Separate box-shadow properties

Tags: css

Is there a way to influence only separate box-shadow properties?

For instance I have these classes to set button size and button color

```
.btn {
    background: gray;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 dark-gray;
}

.btn--primary {
    background: blue;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 dark-blue;
}

.btn--secondary {
    background: red;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 dark-red;
}



.btn--large {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

But now, I also want a larger box shadow on .btn--large

Problem is, I have multiple colored buttons, so I would need some sort of "box-shadow-y-size property"

How do you work around this problem? The only way I can think of right now is to do something like this...

```
.btn--large.btn--primary {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 dark-blue;
}

.btn--large.btn--secondary {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 dark-red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is sadly only one way to define a `box-shadow`, but in your case there might be a work-around. If you don't specify a colour for your `box-shadow` it will default to the colour of the `color` attribute. Perhaps this is something you can make use of.

For example, if you want to be able to have a differently coloured box-shadow while still retaining the original text color, one way you can achieve this by applying the box-shadow to a :before pseudo element instead of the element itself.

[JSFiddle with pseudo element solution](http://jsfiddle.net/S6hVY/1/)

Comment: I have read about this, sadly, my text-color has to be a different color. Also, I've read (not tested) that safari renders the shadow transparent in that case.

Comment: Well, at least Safari 7.0.3 and as far back as Safari 6 behaves as expected, which depending on your user base should probably cover the absolute majority of the Safari users. About the text-color problem, there are several ways that you can work around this, but you might need to be a little creative depending on what your requirements are :). I updated my answer with one possible solution to this problem.